# Giving somebody medicine against their will

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, medical, family-law, new-jersey

Consider the case where an adult son is caring for his parent with dementia. The parent is considered legally competent and has been prescribed certain drugs by the parent's doctor.

The patient takes the medicine for a while and then refuses the medicine. Would it be legal for the son to sneak the medicine into the patient's food in violation of the patient's wishes?

Note: I am in the United States

Comment: Do you care about jurisdiction? The answer might greatly differ between countries where euthanasia is legal and those where it's not. Also, it will depend on whether the parent can clearly express his will to not take the medicine versus he just refuses (or even forgets) to take them due to his mental state.

Comment: @PMF Yes, I care about the jurisdiction. I am in the United States in the state of NJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no specific laws tailored to this scenario, but one might derive an answer from more general laws, in particular battery laws. In the US, [it is reported](https://jaapl.org/content/40/2/239) that there are (as of 21012) no court ruling on the practice of covert medication, and no statutes. However, there are general medico-legal doctrines, informed consent
(e.g. Salgo v. Leland Stanford University, Natanson v. Kline etc.) and the right to refuse medication (Superintendent of Belchertown State School v. Saikewicz, Sell v. US). However these doctrines are based on doctor-patient relations (would be applicable to medical staff sneaking drugs into a patient's food and drink), and have not been applied to family-member care-givers. There is legal risk when a person has not been adjudicated to be incompetent, since this is technically assault.